# Adding Records in a Table using ACCESS VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

My Code is:

```vb
Public Sub ImportCommonFields()

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Imported Table" & " " & TableCtr)
    Set cf = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CommonFields")
    
    cf.AddNew
    cf("FieldNames") = rs1.Fields

    cf.Update
    Set fld = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am currently getting the column names (Fields) from the table in rs1 and would like to import them to an existing table "CommonFields" under the column "FieldNames".

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do.  Do you want to add a record in `cf` for each field in `rs1` ?  If that's the case then you need to loop over the `rs1` fields and call `cf.AddNew` for each field.

Comment: You want to save field names of one table into a single column of another table? Why - what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: I think OP just want to add records from a table of specific column to another table.

Comment: Hi guys correct. The table Imported Table will always change and i would like to keep all the column names of all the tables that has been imported

Answer (score 1):

Loop the Fields collection:

```vb
Public Sub ImportCommonFields()

    Dim fld     As DAO.Field

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Imported Table" & " " & TableCtr)
    Set cf = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CommonFields")
    
    For Each fld In rs1.Fields
        cf.AddNew
        cf("FieldNames").Value = fld.Name
        cf.Update
    Next

    cf.Close
    rs1.Close

    Set fld = Nothing

End Sub
```